# meaning of reference and pointer together?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

In my project, there is a definition of a function call like this.

```
    int32 Map(void * &pMemoryPointer)
```

In the calling place, the paramenter passed is void*, why cant we just receive it as a pointer itself, instead of this?

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing what the `Map` function does, I'd guess that it *sets* the pointer. Therefore it has to be passed by reference.

---

Using a reference to a pointer, you can allocate memory and assign it to the pointer inside the function. For example

```
void DoSomething(int*& pointerReference)
{
    // Do some stuff...

    pointerReference = new int[someSize];

    // Do some other stuff...
}
```

The other way to make functions like that is to return the pointer, but as the `Map` function in the question returns something else that can't be used.

Comment: This is what they have done inside the function exactly, now I understood it completely. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Reading it backwards, this means that `pMemoryPointer` is a reference (`&`) to a pointer (`*`) to `void`. This means that whatever pointer you pass gets referenced, and any modification that the function will do to `pMemoryPointer` will also affect the original (passed) pointer (e.g. changing the value of `pMemoryPointer` will also change the value of the original pointer).

> why cant we just receive it as a pointer itself, instead of this?

That's because by doing that, you are copying the pointer and any change that you'll make to the copy doesn't reflect to the original one.

```
void im_supposed_to_modify_a_pointer(void* ptr) {  // Oh no!
   ptr = 0xBADF00D;
}

int* my_ptr = 0xD0GF00D;
im_supposed_to_modify_a_pointer(my_ptr);
ASSERT(my_ptr == 0xBADF00D) // FAIL!
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird function prototype IMHO, but it means 
(**Update**) that the Map function accepts a reference to a void pointer as a parameter.

So I think, it is equivalent to declaring the function like this:

```
 int32 Map(void** pMemoryPointer)
```

Comment: it is only "equivalent" if pointers and references were equivalent

Comment: @newacct: that's right.
Adding that useful link here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c